# Replacing values of a python ndarray satisfying certain threshold

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, where-clause

I would like to replace the values of a huge python ndarray that are within a certain threshold to 0. Say within the threshold of `[-0.1 and 0.1]`. What is the most efficient way? This is a fairly large array:

```
>>>np.shape(np_w)
shape=(1, 1, 1024, 1024) dtype=float32
```

I know we don't have Matlab's `ismember` here, however, searching numpy docs, I found `np.in1d` and `np.isin`. My solution so far doesn't look good and slow:

```
import numpy as np
Threshhold=X

res=np.isin(np_w,np_w[(np_w>=-Threshhold) & (np_w<=Threshhold)])
indicesToReplace=np.where(res)
np_w[indicesToReplace]=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a symmetric interval around `0` you could use `abs` and `<` and [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) (similar to [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) but in this case you don't need the `np.where` around the condition):

```
my_np[abs(my_np) <= treshhold] = 0
```

This will replace all values whose absolute is smaller than or equal to threshold with `0`.

In case you need a more general solution, say the absolute of the lower threshold is not equal to the upper threshold, then you can combine the expressions using `&`:

```
my_np[(my_np >= lower_treshhold) & (my_np <= upper_threshhold)] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, @MSeifert. So basically your approach is just a one-liner? No need for `np.isin`, right?

Comment: This is unfortunately very slow

Comment: Slow? Compared to what?

Comment: to my method which I first find the indices and then replace them with new values. I would say 10x slower

Comment: @Amir Interesting, you might want to include your arrays. On my computer your approach is ~20 times slower. (array with 100k elements, my approach: 1.6ms, your approach 36ms)

Comment: This is a huge array of more than a million elements. Has the following `shape=(1, 1, 512, 512) dtype=float32` shape.

Comment: @Amir `np_w` or `my_np`? It would make sense to update (edit) the question.

Comment: @Amir I think your timing may be flawed. Even with that shape and dtype my approach is, on my computer at least, several times (25 times) faster.

Comment: Yes, my bad @MSeifert. This is fast and acceptable :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use a combination of [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> threshold = 0.5
>>> my_arr = np.random.randn(20)
>>> my_arr
array([-0.28094279,  1.28432282,  0.2585762 ,  0.41902366,  1.21350506,
       -0.40586786, -1.04135578, -1.06168061,  0.25554365, -0.75404457,
        1.4755498 , -0.14902854,  0.15225808,  0.03667505,  0.6158351 ,
        0.05171262,  1.09116325, -0.5897306 , -0.69801693, -0.31560829,
       -0.36665813, -0.98115761,  1.21050881,  0.66356061, -0.03960144])
>>> my_arr[np.where(np.logical_and(np.greater(my_arr, -threshold), np.less(my_arr, threshold)))[0]] = np.nan
>>> my_arr
array([        nan,  1.28432282,         nan,         nan,  1.21350506,
               nan, -1.04135578, -1.06168061,         nan, -0.75404457,
        1.4755498 ,         nan,         nan,         nan,  0.6158351 ,
               nan,  1.09116325, -0.5897306 , -0.69801693,         nan,
               nan, -0.98115761,  1.21050881,  0.66356061,         nan])
```